# How to pass two lists to another screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to pass to lists which are destinations and coordinates. I had to separate them because I have to scrape the data first then geocode them. Here is my code:

```
Future<void> getCoordinates()async{
for(int i=1 ; i < destination.length ; i++){
  coordinates = await locationFromAddress('${destination.elementAt(i).destination}');
  location.add(coordinates);
  print('$i $location');
}
```

}

Heres a snippet to go from my first screen to second screen:

```
return GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PlaceInfo(packageModel: destination[index], location: location[index])),
                  );
                },
```

Here is a snippet of my second screen:

```
  final PackageModel packageModel;
  final Location location;
  PlaceInfo({Key? key,required this.location, required this.packageModel,}):super(key:key);

  @override
  State<PlaceInfo> createState() => _PlaceInfoState();
}

class _PlaceInfoState extends State<PlaceInfo> {

  //late double _latitude = 2.8025;
  //late double _longitude = 101.7989;

  late double _latitude = widget.location.latitude;
  late double _longitude = widget.location.longitude;
```

When I do this it shows in the app the red error which is

```
type 'List<Location>' is not a subtype of type 'Location'
```

Can somebody please help

Comment: The issue is that in your PlaceInfo class, you are accepting Location object, but sending List<Location> from your GestureDetector,(this line: Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PlaceInfo(packageModel: destination[index], location: location[index])),
                  );), probably location[index] gives List<Location> and not Location as you are expecting.

Comment: What does your function locationFromAddress() return?, based on that we can proceed further.

Comment: @SuvashBhandari it returns the timestamp, latitude and longitude

Comment: So its a list then?

Comment: @SuvashBhandari yes, however I already solved it, I just needed to create an object `Location`  and assign `coordinates[0]` to the object. Then I can add to list `locations`. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lies in this: `location.add(coordinates);`.

It appears that `coordinates` itself is a `List` and you are trying to add it as an element.

Try to first create a `Location` 0bject from `coordinates` and then add that object to the list `location`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes this one did! thank you for your help! :)

Comment: If it served your purpose, pl accept this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be as per your error in my opinion one potential solution is when you are passing arguments to next screen you need to change the type of the argument same as below

```
 Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PlaceInfo(packageModel: destination[index], location: (location[index] as Location))),
                  );
```

You just need to add **as Location** after the location[index]

And another solution is you can declare your List location variable as

```
List<Location> location.....
```